# Getting height difference of area

Tags: openstreetmap, parcel

I am using OpenStreetMap for showing my user a map within my web frontend. A user can mark on the map his parcel.

I would like to automatically get from the marked area information about the height difference on the parcel. Is this possible with OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap does not have elevation data, so you cannot do this using only OpenStreetMap data. There are multiple web services available for looking up elevations, and you could implement this using one of those services.